# How to send socket object as a argument in thread in python3?

Tags: multithreading, sockets, python-3.x

I want to send `socket` object of coming request in thread so that I may communicate with it further. I am sending it via `args=c` but it is not working.

```
import socket
import sys
import json
import threading

class server6:

    s = socket.socket()
    host = socket.gethostname()
    port = 123
    s.bind((host,port))
    s.listen(5)

    while True:
        c, addr = s.accept()
        print("Connection accepted from " + repr(addr[1]))
        print(str(c) + " :: " +str(addr))
        threading.Thread(target=threadMine, args=c).start()

    c.close()

    def threadMine(self, socket sock):
        #print("Thread"+ sock)
```

Can someone take a glance at it?

Comment: What does "but it is not working" mean? Do you get an exception?

Comment: @Rohit Not yet. I just want to know how to pass the socket of incoming user for further communication?

Comment: The `args` keyword to the `Thread` constructor needs to be a tuple. The call should be: `threading.Thread(target=threadMine, args=(c,)).start()`. What you have here should generate an exception in the new thread. Also, the signature for `threadMine` is not standard Python syntax; it should just have `sock` as the second parameter, without the `socket` part. Is this exactly the code you're running? Please give more information about how it is failing.